# Which is a better input for an autoencoder, one with correlated features or one with uncorrelated features?

Tags: correlation, feature-selection, autoencoder

I am trying to visualise my data in 2D in order to detect fraud (outliers), all my features are likely to take bigger values in case of a fraud. But I was careful not to include redundant features,

for example the features :
Activity (a score that is higher for active users who use the service everyday) and Money-earned both tend to take higher values in case of fraud, but one can't be deduced from the other.

I figured that choosing features in this way will translate to bigger coordinates in the 2D representation and would make fraudulent points distant/stand out from the rest of my data.

I also feel like having correlated features would make it easier for autoencoder to reconstruct the data. But I read many times that having correlated features isn’t efficient in machine learning.

Should I make an effort to make my features less correlated ? For example replacing the Activity score (higher for active users) with the times between two uses (lower for active users)?

Or maybe this isn't important for the autoencoder?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about your understanding that "having correlated features would make it easier for autoencoder to reconstruct the data".

For example, in case all your data points are i.i.d. Gaussian it would make data compression very difficult for autoencoders since they would fail to learn a low dimensional representation of the data.

Please refer to this Stanford UFLDL Tutorial [link](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/Autoencoders/) for details.

Comment: Please make your answer useful even without a link